# How to send email automatically when AWS is manually restarted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am beginner in AWS..My application hangs due to some performance issues. So we usually restart the application manually. I would like to send out email to a group when the application is restarted manually..Can any body help me out?

It is a jsf application with tomcat linux environment..To restart, go to Elastic Beanstalk in deployment & management..Click on an instance..Restart using the "Restart App server" option from action button drop down...

Comment: What's the application written in? How do you restart it?

Comment: It is a jsf application with tomcat environment..To restart, go to Elastic Beanstalk in deployment & management..Click on an instance..Restart using the "Restart App server" option from action button drop down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a post hook in **/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/restartappserver/post**  to send an email after completing the restart process. You need to use EB container commands and shell commands to get this done.

*Please note that the post folder is not available by default. So you will have to create it*